# asp.net web service using SOAP with jquery ajax getting error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, soap

I am getting error when i call web service using ajax i try and search every thing but i am unable to resolve this issue.

below is my webservice class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebServiceHome
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class WebServiceHome : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebServiceHome () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public int converttodaysweb(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        int datetodays = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).Days;
        return datetodays;

    }

    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetData()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> name = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        name.Add("1", "Rashid");
        name.Add("2", "Burhan");
        string myJsonString = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(name);

        return myJsonString;
    }

}
```

it is working fine with **invoke** button but it is not working fine when i was trying to call with jquery ajax.

[Invoke click button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BQVa.png)

But When i try to call above method using jquery ajax i am getting some error,below is my jquery ajax calling

```
var GetJson = function () {
            var requestdata = {};
            requestdata.id = "";
            var pdata = "";
            var Requrl = "http://localhost:51120/WebServiceNew/WebServiceHome.asmx/GetData";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: Requrl,
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                }
            });
        }
```

i am getting below error

[Ajax calling error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB0jW.png)

[Jquery Ajax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExF0X.png)

Please check my **webconfig**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpSoap"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
        <!-- Documentation enables the documentation/test pages -->
        <add name="Documentation"/>
      </protocols>

    </webServices>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you seem to have a CORS error. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for a good summary. Basically you need to add the appropriate response headers into your WebService's HTTP response in order to allow cross-domain requests to be made from a browser. (cross-domain means the client (browser) and server are on a different hostname or IP address, or even the same hostname but a different port). How you do this depends on your setup but I would guess there is documentation on it for this kind of service available online somewhere.

Comment: Looks like you have got some config to add custom headers already, but seems like you haven't done everything necessary. I think at least you need to allow handling of OPTIONS requests. You might need to allow that in IIS too.

Comment: @ADyson,can you please share with me any link or example ?

Comment: I forgot to say also remove `crossDomain: true` from your ajax settings. This is just used to simulate a CORS request even when it's not necessary. It's not useful unless you're trying to test that functionality on the server specifically, which it doesn't sound like you are. P.S. If I knew a specific link or whatever to an example for your exact situation I would have given it already. But I'm sure you can type into google just as efficiently as I can.